# How to select values from XML in SQL

Tags: sql, xml, sql-server-2008

Im trying to get the values from some XML in SQL but struggling with the final part, how can I get the values from this?

```
DECLARE @Info XML
SET @Info=N'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<ArrayOfDriveData xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <DriveData>
    <DriveName>C:\</DriveName>
    <DriveSpace>429223288832</DriveSpace>
  </DriveData>
  <DriveData>
    <DriveName>I:\</DriveName>
    <DriveSpace>228759863296</DriveSpace>
  </DriveData>
</ArrayOfDriveData>'


-- Declare a handle for the xml document    
DECLARE @idoc INT

-- Prepare the xml 
EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @idoc OUTPUT, @Info

SELECT 
    *
FROM 
    OPENXML (@idoc, '/ArrayOfDriveData/DriveData/,3)
```

The results I get are:

```
id | parentid | nodetype | localname| namespaceuri | datatype | prev | text
4   0   1   DriveData   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
5   4   1   DriveName   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
10  5   3   #text   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    C:\
6   4   1   DriveSpace  NULL    NULL    NULL    5   NULL
11  6   3   #text   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    429223288832
7   0   1   DriveData   NULL    NULL    NULL    4   NULL
8   7   1   DriveName   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
12  8   3   #text   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    I:\
9   7   1   DriveSpace  NULL    NULL    NULL    8   NULL
13  9   3   #text   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    228759863296
```

It seems the only columns I need are localname and Text, Ideall I would like the result to look like:

```
Drive | Space
    C:\  123456
```

This has probably been asked before but I couldnt see anyone answering how to do it (lots of data on how to get XML from a table, not much on how to get data into a table from XML) and my experience in this area is a bit lacking so i'm stuck on how to finish this off.

Thanks

Comment: Searched for #text and got this.... and the answer .... :)  Thanks.  Saved me much frustration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to stick with openxml its

```
SELECT 
    DriveName, DriveSpace
FROM 
    OPENXML (@idoc, '/ArrayOfDriveData/DriveData',3)
    with (DriveName varchar(10) 'DriveName', DriveSpace varchar(20) 'DriveSpace)
```

That does, of course, put the DriveSpace into a varchar, but you can change that to whatever datatype you need.

I do also want to point out that what GSerg posted below is generally considered the more correct way to do it these days.  OPENXML is an older method.

Comment: XPath should be `/ArrayOfDriveData/DriveData` with no trailing slash I believe and missing a closing quote on `'DriveSpace'`

Comment: I only get null values back from that :(  If there is an easier way than openXML im all for using that, just openXML seemed fairly compact etc

Comment: @Purplegoldfish see my comment

Comment: Awesome thanks @SirCrispalot when i removed that / it works perfectly, and Bert thanks for such a quick reply I can now get on with the project :D

Comment: Yes, what GSerg posted is easier and a more modern way to do it.

Comment: Thanks also Sir Crispalot, I had copied that from the OP.

Answer (score 4):

Just plain query it.

```
select
  t.drivedata.value('DriveName[1]', 'varchar(max)'),
  t.drivedata.value('DriveSpace[1]', 'bigint')
from
  @info.nodes('/ArrayOfDriveData/DriveData') as t(drivedata);
```